# on mouseenter, add class, but remove all other classes

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` container, with 4 child `p`s. When you `mouseenter` a `p`, you add a class to the parent container. However, I'd like the class to remain on the parent container, until I `mouseenter` another `p`. How can I do this with pure Javascript?

I've tried using `mouseout` but it removes the class from the container as soon as I exit the `p` element. I also tried the below before the class is added, but I'm still not getting the effect I'm looking for.

`container.classList.remove("p" + i + "-transform");`

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");

var enterMouse = function(i) {
  p[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    if (i === 0) {
      container.classList.remove("p" + i + "-transform"); // doesn't work
      container.classList.add("p0-transform");
    } else if (i === 1) {
      container.classList.remove("p" + i + "-transform"); // doesn't work
      container.classList.add("p1-transform");
    } else if (i === 2) {
      container.classList.remove("p" + i + "-transform"); // doesn't work
      container.classList.add("p2-transform");
    } else if (i === 3) {
      container.classList.remove("p" + i + "-transform"); // doesn't work
      container.classList.add("p3-transform");
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  enterMouse(i);
}
```

```css
.p0-transform {
  background-color: red;
}

.p1-transform {
  background-color: green;
}

.p2-transform {
  background-color: orange;
}

.p3-transform {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove multiple classes with `classList.remove()`, even if they don't exist on the element, so just remove them all by passing them all to `.remove()`.

You can also get rid of that redundant code, since the `i` is available to concatenate into the class when doing the `.add()`.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
var classes = [].map.call(p, function(_, i) { return "p" + i + "-transform" })

function enterMouse(i) {
  p[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    container.classList.remove.apply(container.classList, classes);
    container.classList.add("p" + i + "-transform");
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  enterMouse(i);
}
```

```css
.p0-transform {
  background-color: red;
}

.p1-transform {
  background-color: green;
}

.p2-transform {
  background-color: orange;
}

.p3-transform {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

If there will never be any other classes on the `container`, then you can simply clear the `.className` property with `container.className = ""`

---

Here's how I'd write the code with modern features and a little extra tweaking:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const classes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p"), function(el, i) {
  const cls = "p" + i + "-transform";

  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    container.classList.remove(...classes);
    container.classList.add(cls);
  });

  return cls;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't scale well as the number of elements increases

Comment: @mhodges: Given that the classes are `i` based, that's a minor issue, though I'll update it to deal with that possibility.

Answer (score -1):

You can fully dump the element's CSS classes by setting its `className` property to an empty string.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");

var enterMouse = function(i) {
  p[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    if (i === 0) {
      container.className = ""; // works now
      container.classList.add("p0-transform");
    } else if (i === 1) {
      container.className = ""; // works now
      container.classList.add("p1-transform");
    } else if (i === 2) {
      container.className = ""; // works now
      container.classList.add("p2-transform");
    } else if (i === 3) {
      container.className = ""; // works now
      container.classList.add("p3-transform");
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  enterMouse(i);
}
```

```css
.p0-transform {
  background-color: red;
}

.p1-transform {
  background-color: green;
}

.p2-transform {
  background-color: orange;
}

.p3-transform {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. does this delete all classes on the parent container? because what if the container has pre-existing classes. I only want to delete these 4 classes, but no the pre-existing ones

Comment: Yes, it would remove _all_ classes on `container`. Your original post didn't mention the need to keep other classes, although your use of `classList` should have clued me in.